# Symfony Custom ChoiceType Filtered By Other Object

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

```
class User 
{
    public $id;
    public $username;

    public function getCompanies()
    {
        //stuff
    }
}

class Company 
{
    public $id;
    public $name;

    public static function getForUser(User $user) 
    {
        //stuff
    }
}
```

I have the above two models and want to create a reusable custom `ChoiceType` field that will be a select box of filtered `Company` ids (or objects) based on a User object.  If no `User` is supplied, then have a `ChoiceType` (select box) of all Company objects.

How do I go about this?  I've been going around in circles reading the Symfony docs and can't seem to find any examples similar to my needs.

I can either use `getForUser()` from the Company class or `getCompanies()` from the User class (they pretty much do the same thing).

There is no direct relationship between Company and User.  They are 'joined' through other objects/tables (Manager/Customer/Contact).

```
class CompanyType extends AbstractType 
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('company', ChoiceType::class, array(
            "choices" => ??????
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return ChoiceType::class;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Company::class,
        ));
    }

}
```

All help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html ?

Comment: I did something similar and the approach I used was to create a 'contact' entity which identified a contact by the company id and the person associated with it.  The selection was based off a query that offered both established contacts and users which had not yet been identified as contacts.  My solution used Ajax, so the field type was text, with a JSON back end.

Comment: @JasonRoman I did.  I couldn't figure out how to use 'How to dynamically Generate Forms Based on user Data' properly.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to try this link:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
// ...

$builder->add('users', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle:Company',
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->orderBy('u.name', 'ASC');   //or DESC
    },
    'choice_label' => 'username',
));
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think what you have given and linked to is an example of how to get a select box of 'User' objects but I want a select box of `Company` objects based on which companies a user is part of.